# GPS Signal Strength Calculation

Tags: c#, geolocation, gps, gis, nmea

I want to display a signal bar for a GPS device using .NET CF. I'm able to read NMEA data and get the SNR signals. But they are a number of satellites with some active and some inactive with various SNRs. I thought about getting average of total SNR but it won't give a accurate value as three strong signal satellite is enough for GPS fix and with another 5 satellites with bad SNR can mess up the signal bar calculation. How am I gonna calculate GPS signal in percentages in a proper way?

Comment: Take the average of the X strongest signals?

Comment: is it a standard way or just your idea?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the `GSA` NMEA sentance to get the `Dilution of Precision`:

> This sentence provides details on the
>   nature of the fix. It includes the
>   numbers of the satellites being used
>   in the current solution and the DOP.
>   DOP (dilution of precision) is an
>   indication of the effect of satellite
>   geometry on the accuracy of the fix.
>   It is a unitless number where smaller
>   is better. For 3D fixes using 4
>   satellites a 1.0 would be considered
>   to be a perfect number, however for
>   overdetermined solutions it is
>   possible to see numbers below 1.0.

From [GPS info](http://www.gpsinformation.org/dale/nmea.htm#GSA).

A DOP value of 1 is perfect, while a DOP value of 20 or greater is poor.  You typically want a DOP of less than 10.

Answer (score 7):

No, don´t use the DOP, use the HDOP (horicontal dilution of precision) value.
The DOP does includes the altitude (height above elipsoid/sea level).
Since the altitude is not very accurate, GPS is mostly used for horicontal (lat, lon) positions. Therefore the hdop is more useful.
You typically will use hdop < 5 values.

Another way:
The answer above, calculates the quality related to a specific location, and time. 
If you really want the signal strength, e.g for comparing the quality of the installation of the GPS receiver inside a vehicle, or the quality of the antenna: Then you should average the Signal to Noise ratio of all used! satellites. You will find this in the GSV sentences.
As far as I know, there is no standard way to compute the overall signal strength.
But I would not use this to show bars on a display, its more for analysis and monitoring.

Answer (score 0):

There is sentence called

***$PGRME Estimated Position Error*** [1.NMEA0183 Ref]

which I would say it's exactly what we are looking for but unfortunately it is Garmin's proprietary sentence. It makes me think calculating such a thing might have a fair amount of work that Garmin tried to brand it for it's own protocol.

Also about the suggestion of using **GSA**.
When I am looking at this sentence, there is no DOP in it. searching give me 
***"$PGRMF Position Fix Sentence"*** which is again a Garmin proprietary sentence.

As I can see only **GGA** sent. has the Horizontal Dilution of precision.

*I would like to know if I need specific Garmin compatible hardware to read Garmin sentences or there is another solution.*